# Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM - Flask

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Can anyone provide guidance on why this simple Flask app complains about `Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM`. I'm not attempting to load more than one context, obviously.
Code:

```
import flask
from pyspark  import SparkContext
from operator import itemgetter

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return 'Example: /dt/140'

@app.route('/dt/<int:delaythreshold>')
def dt(delaythreshold):
    global flights_rdd

    flights_dict =                                         \
        flights_rdd                                        \
        .filter( lambda (day, delay): delay >= threshold ) \
        .countByValue()
    sorted_flight_tuples = \
        sorted( flights_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True )

    return render_template('delays.html', tuples=sorted_flight_tuples[:5])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global flights_rdd

    sc = SparkContext()
    flights_rdd =                                     \
        sc.textFile('/tmp/flights.csv', 4)            \
          .map( lambda s: s.split(',') )              \
          .map( lambda l: ( l[0][:4], int(lst[1]) ) ) \
          .cache()

    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably shouldn't create "global" resources such as the SparkContext in the `__main__` section.

In particular, if you run your app in debug mode the module is instantly reloaded a second time upon start - hence the attempt to create a second `SparkContext`. (Add e.g. `print 'creating sparkcontext'` to your `__main__` section before creating the `SparkContext` - you'll see it twice).

Check the flask documenation for proposals on how to cache global resources.
Following http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/#context-usage you could e.g. retrieve the SparkContext as follows:

```
from flask import g

def get_flights():
    flights_rdd = getattr(g, '_flights_rdd', None)
    if flights_rdd is None:
        # create flights_rdd on the fly
        sc = g._sc = SparkContext()
        flights_rdd =                                     \
            sc.textFile('/tmp/flights.csv', 4)            \
              .map( lambda s: s.split(',') )              \
              .map( lambda l: ( l[0][:4], int(lst[1]) ) ) \
              .cache()
        g._flights_rdd = flights_rdd
    return flights_rdd

@app.teardown_appcontext
def teardown_sparkcontext(exception):
    sc = getattr(g, '_sc', None)
    if sc is not None:
        sc.close()
```

Then use `flights_rdd = get_flights()` instead of the `global flights_rdd`.

Comment: neat solution, should  the first line in teardown_sparkcontext have sc = ... instead of db = ...

Comment: @Matt Sure - fixed it.